# Create Button based on portrait screen width

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to create a button who's width is half the portrait screen's width, so that when the device is rotated to landscape, the button stays the same size. I want it to work on various screen sizes, so I don't want to hardcode in the width.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do that via xml or at code?

Comment: @gio: My preference is via xml, but I'm not sure that would be possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
if(width>height){
  use height
}
else{
   use witdth
}
```

Use it in onCreate() method of your Activity

Comment: Thanks. If I use this way, then I need to take into account the padding of the ViewGroup that the Button is contained into. So I would need to set my button width to (screenWidth - padding)/2. Is there a way to get that padding in pixels from my parent ViewGroup?

Comment: ((View)button.getParent()).getPaddingLeft()